# split string into key value pair

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to split the following string by comma if it matches `key: value`. Split by comma works until it encounters a comma in the `value`

`const string = "country: Kenya, city: Nairobi, population: 3.375M, democracy-desciption: Work in progress/ Not fully met, obstacles exist"`

I'd like to end up with this result:

```
[[country: Kenya],
[city: Nairobi],
[population: 3.375M],
[democracy-description: Work in progress/ Not fully met, obstacles exist]]
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). *We are very willing to help you fix your code, but we dont write code for you*.

Comment: I have read all that. @NathanP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could split the string by looking if not a comma follows and a colon.

```js
var string = "country: Kenya, city: Nairobi, population: 3.375M, democracy-desciption: Work in progress/ Not fully met, obstacles exist, foo: bar, bar, bar";

console.log(string.split(/, (?=[^,]+:)/).map(s => s.split(': ')));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 6):

Split into an array of key-value pair strings, then map that array to an array of arrays by splitting each pair:

```
const table =
 string.split(",") //["key:value","key:value"]
  .map(pair => pair.split(":")); //[["key","value"],["key","value"]]
```

To built an object out of this:

```
const result = Object.fromEntries(table);

//usable as:
console.log( result.country );
```

or use a Map:

```
const result = new Map(table);

//usable as:
console.log( result.get("country") );
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one...

```
function getParameters() {
    var paramStr = location.search.substring(1).split("&");
    var parameters = {}
    paramStr.map(item=>{
        let keyValue = item.split('=')
        return parameters[keyValue[0]] = keyValue[1];
    })
    return parameters;
}
```