# Typescript convert string to Map

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

I have this string (called currentExecution.variables):

```
{executionid=0c3246fb37e65e3368c8c4f30000016ab593bec244daa8df, timeout=10000}
```

and I need to convert it into a Map so that I can work with the entries, but I'm having a hard time doing this. I've tried, following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46177420/4116960), to transform it into a key-value set of pairs. First I've replaced = with : and { or } with white space, then splitted it according to the answer:

```
newString.split(/,(?=[^,]+:)/).map(s => s.split(': '));
```

but I do not get the proper result, and I'm stuck without the Map.  What's missing? Or is there a better/faster way to do this?

Comment: Assuming that the first part works: you have `'='` to split around, not `': '` (especially not with the space).

Comment: Why? If I have replaced = with :, I can't split around =

Comment: I said that I've replaced my = with :. So the resulting string would be the same as the original but with : instead of =. Then on this string I do the split.

Comment: @Dseaster You are right, I missed that part.

Comment: @Dseaster Map as in the [Map object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), or Map as in just an object, like what parsed json would churn out?

Comment: You replaced the wrong `=`. It is about the second one, in `s.split()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the following

1. Removing the `{` and `}` characters from the start and end the string. Do not use `replace` in case there are any occurrences inside it.
2. Split the result into each discrete chunk that forms key-value pairs.
3. Split those into actual key and value
4. The result can readily be convert to a Map because the constructor [takes an array where each item is an array with two items](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Parameters) and will convert that to a map where the first item is the key, the second the value:

```js
let string = "{executionid=0c3246fb37e65e3368c8c4f30000016ab593bec244daa8df, timeout=10000}";

let keyValuePairs = string.slice(1, -1) //remove first and last character
  .split(/\s*,\s*/)                     //split with optional spaces around the comma
  .map(chunk => chunk.split("="));      //split key=value
  
const map = new Map(keyValuePairs);

console.log(map.get("executionid"));
console.log(map.get("timeout"));
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I meant. Does this solution work with a random number of key=value pairs in String?

Comment: @Dseaster yes, it works with any amount of key-value pairs. You might have a problem if a value includes a comma `,` or if it includes an equals sign `=` - in those cases the split might turn out wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You can work without regexps too, but you have to understand the basic concept of that first you split along the `,`s, and then along the `=`s:

```js
var data = "{executionid=0c3246fb37e65e3368c8c4f30000016ab593bec244daa8df, timeout=10000}";
var pairs = data.substring(1, data.length - 1).split(", "); // step 1, split using commas

var obj = pairs.reduce(function(acc, cur) {
  var pair = cur.split("="); // step 2, split using =
  acc[pair[0].trim()] = pair[1].trim();
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: For me it is right, even if it doesn't return a Map. Don't know why it was considered wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I think somebody just serially downvoted everything here. It's not wrong - I was actually going to add a section for using an object but you beat me to it.

Comment: @Dseaster yes, it was the guy who deleted his answer I think.

Comment: Apparently the user started to downvoting all my past questions. Do you remember his username? I can't find him anymore.

Comment: @Dseaster there is a mechanism which will probably revert it later: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me - so check your history tomorrow.

Comment: (Or this one says 36 hours: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/what-can-i-do-if-im-the-victim-of-serial-downvoting - but in fact I see 2 of your other questions having any downvote)

Answer (score 2):

You can capture the key and value pairs in a capturing group shown in [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/hMFO2G/1/).

Based on that you can go ahead and reduce its value to a Map.

```js
const currentExecutionVariable = "{executionid=0c3246fb37e65e3368c8c4f30000016ab593bec244daa8df, timeout=10000}";

const pattern = /([A-Za-z0-9]+)\=([A-Za-z0-9]+)/g;

const matches = currentExecutionVariable.match(pattern);

const currentExecutionMap = matches.reduce((acc, curr) => {
 const [key, value] = curr.split('=');
 
 if (!acc.has(key)) {
  acc.set(key, value);
 } 
 return acc;
}, new Map());

for (const [key, value] of currentExecutionMap.entries()) {
  console.log (`${key}: ${value}`);
}
```

---

**Update**

Using the captured groups:

```js
const currentExecutionVariable = "{executionid=0c3246fb37e65e3368c8c4f30000016ab593bec244daa8df, timeout=10000}";

const pattern = /([A-Za-z0-9]+)\=([A-Za-z0-9]+)/g;

let currentExecutionMap = new Map();

let capturedGroup;
while ((capturedGroup = pattern.exec(currentExecutionVariable))) {

  // 1st captured group is the key of the map
  const key = capturedGroup[1];

  // 2nd captured group is the value of the map
  const value = capturedGroup[2];

  if (!currentExecutionMap.has(key)) {
    currentExecutionMap.set(key, value);
  }
}

for (const [key, value] of currentExecutionMap.entries()) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}
```

Comment: You don't need to escape `=` in the regex - there is no special meaning to the character. Also, the `.reduce` is not strictly needed, since you can just do `new Map([["key1", "value1"], ["key2", "value2"]])` to populate the map. Still, these are minor points - good solution. The actual improvement I'd suggest is using the capture groups from the regex - doing `pattern.exec(currentExecutionVaruable)` will give the key and value captured, do you don't need to split the result. `while(result = `pattern.exec(currentExecutionVaruable)) map.set(result[1], result[2])`

Comment: @VLAZ I think the splitting of `=` is unnecessary, I will update my answer

Answer (score -1):

I have this string (called stats):

```
active_total: 1087
cumulative: 1
trace_total: 10
```

which is not even in JSON format.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56127699/typescript-convert-string-to-map) is the solution that I am trying:

```
let keyValuePairs = stats
  .split(/\s*\n\s*/)                     //split with optional spaces around the comma
  .map(chunk => chunk.split(": "));      //split key=value
  
const map = new Map(keyValuePairs);

console.log(map.get("sessions_active_total"));
console.log(map.get("cumulative"));
```

But it is throwing compilation error at this line:

```
const map = new Map(keyValuePairs);
```

Error message:

```
error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(iterable: Iterable<readonly [unknown, unknown]>): Map<unknown, unknown>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string[][]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable<readonly [unknown, unknown]>'.
      The types returned by '[Symbol.iterator]().next(...)' are incompatible between these types.
        Type 'IteratorResult<string[], any>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<readonly [unknown, unknown], any>'.
          Type 'IteratorYieldResult<string[]>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<readonly [unknown, unknown], any>'.
            Type 'IteratorYieldResult<string[]>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorYieldResult<readonly [unknown, unknown]>'.
              Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'readonly [unknown, unknown]'.
                Target requires 2 element(s) but source may have fewer.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(entries?: readonly (readonly [unknown, unknown])[]): Map<unknown, unknown>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string[][]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'readonly (readonly [unknown, unknown])[]'.
      Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'readonly [unknown, unknown]'.

58         const map = new Map(keyValuePairs);
```

Comment: This falls under the category of a question, posting this as an answer to someone else's question is totally wrong. Ask a new question to draw more attention to your question and others will do their best to answer it. Cheers and welcome to SO!