# Typescript convert plain string to Map

Tags: javascript, string, typescript, split

I have this string (called stats):

```
active_total: 1087
cumulative: 1
trace_total: 10
```

which is not even in JSON format.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56127699/typescript-convert-string-to-map) is the solution that I am trying:

```
let keyValuePairs = stats
  .split(/\s*\n\s*/)                     //split with optional spaces around the comma
  .map(chunk => chunk.split(": "));      //split key=value
  
const map = new Map(keyValuePairs);

console.log(map.get("sessions_active_total"));
console.log(map.get("cumulative"));
```

But it is throwing compilation error at this line:

```
const map = new Map(keyValuePairs);
```

Error message:

```
error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(iterable: Iterable<readonly [unknown, unknown]>): Map<unknown, unknown>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string[][]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable<readonly [unknown, unknown]>'.
      The types returned by '[Symbol.iterator]().next(...)' are incompatible between these types.
        Type 'IteratorResult<string[], any>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<readonly [unknown, unknown], any>'.
          Type 'IteratorYieldResult<string[]>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<readonly [unknown, unknown], any>'.
            Type 'IteratorYieldResult<string[]>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorYieldResult<readonly [unknown, unknown]>'.
              Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'readonly [unknown, unknown]'.
                Target requires 2 element(s) but source may have fewer.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(entries?: readonly (readonly [unknown, unknown])[]): Map<unknown, unknown>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string[][]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'readonly (readonly [unknown, unknown])[]'.
      Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'readonly [unknown, unknown]'.

58         const map = new Map(keyValuePairs);
```

Answer (score 2):

Typescript is unable to infer the exact result of the `chunk.split(": ")`. Even to be able to remotely guess it typescript should know the runtime value of the `stats` variable.

If you're looking for type safe solution I'd assume to use [custom type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards):

```ts
const isTupleOf2 = (chunk: string[]): chunk is [string, string] => chunk.length === 2

let keyValuePairs = stats
  .split(/\s*\n\s*/)
  .map((chunk: string) => chunk.split(": "))
  .filter(isTupleOf2)      
  
const map = new Map(keyValuePairs);
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WP5GEw)

Or if you're absolutely sure the result will always be the one you expect you may use [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions):

```ts
let keyValuePairs = stats
  .split(/\s*\n\s*/)
  .map((chunk: string) => chunk.split(": ") as [string, string])

const map = new Map(keyValuePairs);
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/Nl0bBN)

Comment: Thank you @aleksxor. I tried with type assertion and this solved my problem.